# Xamarin Forms Editing Item with SQL

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an application where items are added to a collection view and then you can tap on that item where a detail page comes up. With this detail page, you can edit the title and description given and then it should update in the collection view. However, when changes are made to the item, the item is not changed within the observable collection. How do I go about this?

Here is my xaml for the detail page:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="5" Padding="10" AnchorY="0.5">
    <!--<Label Text="Title:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>-->
    <Editor Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Title" TextColor="White"/>
    <!--<Label Text="Note:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White"/>-->
    <Editor Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White"/>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Due Date:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="50,4,0,0" Text="{Binding DueDate}" FontSize="Small" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Text="Save"  
            Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="Black" 
            BorderWidth="1.5"
            BorderColor="White"
            CornerRadius="50">
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is my DataBaseService:

```
public async Task UpdateItem(Item item)
{
    var databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyData3.db");
    var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);

    await db.UpdateAsync(item);
    OnUpdatedItem?.Invoke();
}
```

OnUpdateItem?.Invoked();

```
private void LocalDatabaseService_OnUpdatedItem()
{
    _ = ExecuteLoadItemsCommand();
}
```

and here is the OnSaveChanges

```
private async void OnSaveChanges(Item item)
{
        Text = Text;
        Description = Description;
        DueDate = DueDate;

    await LocalDatabaseService.UpdateItem(item);

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
}
```

LoadItems:

```
async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    try
    {
        Items.Clear();
        var items = await LocalDatabaseService.GetAllItems();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

Item Model:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set
        {
            Text = value;
            if (Text != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                Text = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public string Description 
    { 
        get { return Description; }
        set 
        { Description = value;
            if(Description != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                Description = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: is `ExecuteLoadItemsCommand` actually being executed?

Comment: Yes, you should  first check if event `SaveChangesCommand` be triggered. if it works, then check if model `item` has implemented interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0). For more details, check document  [ViewModels and Property-Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications).

Comment: Both the SaveChangesCommand and the ExecuteLoadItemsCommand is being executed

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I added my INotifyPropertyChange but still can't seem to figure it out, could you please enlighten me on what I have done wrong in the model?

Comment: ItemDetailViewModel is loading a **new copy** of the `Item` from the db, modifying it, and saving it.  So the instance of `Item` that is already in the `ObservableCollection` is not being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted, we found the parameter in method `OnSaveChanges` is useless since it is always null.

You can change your code like this in class `ItemDetailViewModel`:

```
    public Command SaveChangesCommand { get; }
    public ItemDetailViewModel()
    {
        SaveChangesCommand = new Command(OnSaveChanges);
    }
```

And method `OnSaveChanges`:

```
    private async void OnSaveChanges()
    {

        Item item = new Item();
        item.Id = Int32.Parse(ItemId);
        item.Text = Text;
        item.Description = Description;
        item.DueDate = DueDate;

        await LocalDatabaseService.UpdateItem(item);

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
```

Comment: This has fixed issues with my previous Item model code, however the item still does not update. I am unsure whether its not getting the item being parsed through as when adding breakpoints the item being parsed is null? Should this be the case?

Comment: Is it convenient for you to post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi @Tanner,   I have updated my answer, you can check it.